# Convert string to int and test success in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

How can you check whether a **string** is **convertible** to an **int?**

Let's say we have data like "House", "50", "Dog", "45.99", I want to know whether I should just use the **string** or use the parsed **int** value instead.

*In JavaScript we had this [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) function. If the string **couldn't be parsed**, it would get back **NaN**.*

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`Int32.TryParse(String, Int32)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

```
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
  if (result)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
  }
```

Comment: I've been editing it, so any mistakes may have been rectified

Comment: Excellent, and it returns a value indicating whether the conversion succeeded. Thanks!

Comment: +1 I like the solution, but it could be a little more elegant by running it right into the if statement.

Answer (score 13):

Could you not make it a little more elegant by running the tryparse right into the if?

Like so:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(value, out number))     
  Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
```

Answer (score 5):

Int.TryParse

Answer (score 2):

found this in one of the search results: [How do I identify if a string is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-do-i-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Adding this because the answers i saw before did not have usage:

```
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse("123", out n);
```

here `"123"` can be something like string `s = "123"` that the OP is testing and the value `n` will have a value (`123`) after the call if it is found to be numeric.