# c# convert string to int

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

```
converted.Year = textBox2.Text;
textBox17.Text = converted.Year;

int year2 = int.Parse(converted.Year);
converted.Year = year2.ToString();
```

Hi!   I would like the final assigned value of `textBox17` to be of an `int` type.

Initially, I tried:  `textBox17.Text = int.Parse(converted.Year);`

But it only returns an error message that it can't do the conversion.

So I came up with the 2 last lines, but I'm not really sure if it really outputs an `int`?
I think I probably have walked in circles around the problem?  Hmm...

Comment: Int.Parse is going to take a string that already has an int-compatible value (such as "32") and convert it into an Int object (32). That doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do. Can you give more details?

Comment: The type of `textBox17.Text` is not `int`. It's `string`, that's why you cannot assign an `int` to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405619/convert-string-to-int-and-test-success-in-c-sharp

Comment: You could have at least tried to use variables that are more meaningful than `converted` or `textbox17`.

Comment: If you're just trying to validate that converted.Year can be parsed as an integer, look into int.TryParse(converted.Year).

Comment: What type does `converted.Year` have?

Answer (score 3):

The type of `textbox17.Text` is `string` and will always be `string`. You can certainly use it to display integers though.

There is a [NumericUpDown control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you can use to display numbers that accepts only numbers. To force integer display just set its [DecimalPlaces property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to 0.

Comment: I want the numerical string value entered in textBox2,  show up in textBox17   as  an int  value. is it possible ?

Comment: @CrystaliseMoriwaki: Yes it is. You need to add a TextChanged event handler to textBox2. In the handler read the string value in textBox2 and do an int.TryCast() on it. If the cast works, assign it to textBox17. If not, set it to "error" or some message of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You've got:

```
converted.Year = textBox2.Text;
textBox17.Text = converted.Year;
```

This is valid although all you're doing is copying a string around.

Then you've got:

```
int year2 = int.Parse(converted.Year);
```

Which is also fine - but will crash if the string isn't representative of an int ("32" is fine, "bob" will crash as will "32bob")

Then you've got:

```
converted.Year = year2.ToString();
```

Which, if it hasn't crashed - shouldn't give any value different from your first line above.

Answer (score 1):

The textBox.Text can only accept a string.  So you will have to use int.Parse and ToString when getting/setting the text.