# How to input multiple zero as string to int?

Tags: c#, string, int

I have a value `"0001"` as `string`.

So, how to insert the value to field with type data `int`?

I work in c#

```
example :
string val = "0001";
int getVal = val;
```

Comment: Or...http://stackoverflow.com/q/405619/327083 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/952469/327083 ...  Also, there is the painfully easy-to-find documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods. **But remember**, `0001` is just a *textual representation* of a number... i.e. a `string`. When you parse this string, you will get `1` not `0001`. There is nothing `0001` as an `int`.

```
string val = "0001";
int getval;
if (Int32.TryParse(val, out getval))
{
     //Successfull parsing
}
else
{
     //Your string is not a valid integer.
}
```

Difference between these methods is; [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx) if your string is not a valid `Int32`. But [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't throw any exception in any case. It just returns `false` if parsing is not succeed.

Comment: the return is "1".. i want to input in table "0001".

Comment: @user3747046 As I said, you can't have an `int` as a `0001`. Leading zeros are not allowed for integers. `0001` is just a `string` representation of it. What is "table" in your case? Is it a database table? If it is, then you can define your column type as a character (`nvarchar` for example) and you can insert `0001` value as a `string` without any parsing operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a string to an int by using `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` which won't throw an exception if the parsing fails.

However be aware that `0001` and `1` are represented in the exact same way when converted to integer. If you require the trailing zeroes, then you have to retain the string and convert to an int only when you need to do calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Leading zeros are not allowed for integers, but maybe this article can help you

[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
int getVal;
string val = "0001";
Int.tryparse(val,out int getVal);
```

For more information http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int-Parse-Convert-ToInt-and is a tutorial

tell me any number that is 0001 and not 1? they are the same. It depends on how you print the number or store the number back in a string.

Comment: the return is "1".. i want to input in table "0001".

Comment: well, tell me any number that is 0001? . It depends on how you print the number or store the number in a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string val = "0001"; 
int getVal = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```